# Incremental build for Android project using Ant

Tags: android, ant

My server needs to keep building a large amount of Android projects. All of them are almost identical except for minor change on manifest.xml or any resource file (if it's better for the task) for each build. To reduce cost and improve efficiency, I try to implement incremental build. My planned procedures are:

1. after the first successful build, skip all the previous
   procedures (aapt to generate R.java, adle to make java, etc.)
2. directly call aapt to make resource files, e.g., *.ap_
3. call apkbuilder to make classes.dex and usigned.apk
4. make signed.apk

So my question is whether the above solution is possible? And any clue about how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a solution for your particular requirements but perhaps it will provide you with some useful pointers.

I have [an Antlib](https://github.com/rectangularsoftware/rectangular-antlib) that I use for building Android projects.  You probably won't want to use it yourself as it has some drawbacks, but it should serve as an example of how to perform the various steps to build an Android app using Ant.  In particular, it shows how to call the various Android SDK tools from Ant and how to use the Ant `uptodate` task and Ant's [`if` and `unless` attributes](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) to avoid processing files that haven't changed.

The source for the Android Ant macros is [here](https://github.com/rectangularsoftware/rectangular-antlib/blob/master/src/xml/com/rectangularsoftware/antlib/antlib.xml) (the Antlib [documentation](https://github.com/rectangularsoftware/rectangular-antlib/wiki) might help you to make sense of what it's doing).